# How match with pattern and "like" operator escaping sware brackets ([]) in .net

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns, square-bracket

This method returns true when it shouldn't

```
pattern = "*[cryptservice@inbox.ru]*"
file = "test.pdf"
    If file Like pattern Then
        MsgBox("like method, file: " & file)
    End If
```

for every file i put into the var file, i get true in this line:

```
If file Like pattern Then
```

the real true should appear at

```
file = "P0LRBE2RUK[cryptservice@inbox.ru].awes0me"
```

So, how can I escape the square bracket ([]) for a search Pattern (not regex)

BTW I've a list of pattern from an API (https://fsrm.experiant.ca/), and i can't use:

```
For Each file In IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern,IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Because the IO.Directory.GetFiles throw an exception for denied folders

Answer (score 0):

Not the best method but works

```
Function WildcardToRegex(pattern As String) As String
    Return "^" + Regex.Escape(pattern).Replace("\*", ".*").Replace("\?", ".") + "$"
End Function

Function wildcardRegexMatch(wildcard As String, s As String) As Boolean
    Dim regexPattern As Regex = New Regex(WildcardToRegex(wilcard))
    Return regexPattern.IsMatch(s)
End Function
```

:D